# Need to update the ALTER TYPE object

Tags: oracle, alter, user-defined-types

I have created  an `TYPE object` named `example1` using following query.

```
create or replace type example1 as  object
                          (emp_name varchar2(32)
                          ,emp_location varchar2(32)
                          )
```

Later I tried to change the length of the variable `emp_location` to    `varchar(36)`   and I tried multiple ways

```
ALTER TYPE Point ADD ATTRIBUTE emp_location varchar2(36) CASCADE;
```

and I end with the following object.

```
create or replace type example1 as  object
                          (emp_name varchar2(32)
                          ,emp_location varchar2(32)
                          )

 Alter type example1 modify attribute emp_location varchar(36) cascade
 Alter type example1 modify attribute emp_location varchar2(37) cascade
 ALTER TYPE example1 DROP ATTRIBUTE emp_location INVALIDATE
 ALTER TYPE example1 ADD ATTRIBUTE emp_location varchar2(38) CASCADE
```

Now I want to remove the following

```
 Alter type example1 modify attribute emp_location varchar(36) cascade
 Alter type example1 modify attribute emp_location varchar2(37) cascade
 ALTER TYPE example1 DROP ATTRIBUTE emp_location INVALIDATE
 ALTER TYPE example1 ADD ATTRIBUTE emp_location varchar2(38) CASCADE
```

How can  I do that ?

Comment: Except for the confusion of  type name (`example1` or `point`?) your code runs. So what is your question? What do you want us to help you with?

Comment: Hi,Sorry. Type name is  example1.
I wanted to change the  emp_location varchar2(32) to emp_location varchar2(36)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> " I wanted to change the emp_location varchar2(32) to emp_location varchar2(36)"

Well one of the lines of code you posted does that (after correcting the Type name):

```
SQL> create or replace type example1 as  object
  2                       (emp_name varchar2(32)
  3                       ,emp_location varchar2(32)
  4                       )   
  5  /

Type created.

SQL> alter type example1 modify attribute emp_location varchar2(36) cascade
  2  /

Type altered.

SQL> desc example1
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMP_NAME                                           VARCHAR2(32)
 EMP_LOCATION                                       VARCHAR2(36)

SQL>
```